# Why are we advised to put templates in project/app_name/templates/app_name/?

Tags: django, django-templates

In the django tutorial, it recommends that an application's templates go in

`project/app_name/templates/app_name`

which results in them being referred to from views something like this:

```
class ScenarioDetails(generic.DetailView):
    model = Scenario
    template_name= "cmmods/scenario.html"
```

I would like to understand what is behind this recommendation.

I can't see what situation would make it bad to put templates in

`project/app_name/templates`

and refer to them thusly:

```
class ScenarioDetails(generic.DetailView):
    model = Scenario
    template_name= "scenario.html"
```

What is behind this recommendation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It avoids name clashes and it explicitly refers to the app where the template is located.

Say your app defines a couple of templates that are very similar. An easy way to achieve this is to use a base template, e.g. `'base.html'`. This is quite a common name, and it is quite likely that other apps use the same name. If you put this template in your root template folder, the names clash and both apps get the same template, depending on which one comes first (or last) in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

By putting each template in a folder named after your app, you avoid these name clashes. It is also easier to locate the template from just the template name, which is very useful if your app uses templates from other apps.

Say you use the template `detail.html` in your `app2` app. Django will look for this template in *all* template folders in the order they are found. Now, your installed apps looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'app1',
    'app2',
)
```

Django will look for the `detail.html` file in the following locations, and picks the first one it finds:

```
/path/to/project/app1/templates/detail.html
/path/to/project/app2/templates/detail.html
```

Even though `app2` expects the template file in `app2/templates/`, Django will give the template in `app1/templates/` if it exists. You get the wrong template because the (relative) names are the same.

Now, if you would put your template in `app2/templates/app2/detail.html`, you are sure you get the right template.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry I don'y quite follow.  Are you saying I can't safely have a different base.html in each application's `app_name/template/` folder?   I _think_ (though I have to go searching) that the same tutorial I'm recalling did suggest that base.html (only) goes in the application's root template folder!

Comment: @GreenAsJade Ok, that might be a confusing example, as many sites have a `base.html` template in the root folder that defines the base structure of _every_ html page in the site. As this is a project-wide template (and not app-specific), it should indeed reside in the root template folder. But say you have a `detail.html` for a model in your app. If it resides in the root of your template folder, and another app defines the same `detail.html` for another model, the template finder will only ever find one of these templates, and one of the apps ends up using the wrong template.

Comment: So I think what you're saying is that even though a view is "in" a specific application, nonetheless the template finder can't take advantage of this to determine which template to choose?   It can't say "this view is in app1, so I will use `app1/templates/detail.html`"

Comment: @GreenAsJade It won't, as that is not how the template system is designed. The way it is now, you can explicitly override templates from other apps by e.g. defining `app1/templates/app2/detail.html`. However, to prevent that you unintentionally override another app's templates, you put them in a subdirectory named after your app.

Comment: To this day I find it baffling that Django has been programmed like this. The templates are in different apps. There should have been no need to create another app1 folder inside the app1 folder. Just increases the number of folders one has to dig into. The creators of Django should've fixed this long ago.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that templates need to be kept separate from templates of other Django apps to prevent collision. This is why all templates in Django apps should be saved in a directory called `app_name/templates/app_name`.

For example, without doing this, two apps with the same template (same filename) would have a problem if they're used together in the same Django project (without additional work, Django wouldn't know which of these `home.html` files to use):

```
app1/templates/home.html
app2/templates/home.html
```

As a result of the convention to include the app name in the templates path, you can safely create and release a Django app and reuse it in other Django projects without fearing that there will be a filename problem.

Comment: This is not entirely true: collectstatic doesn't collect template files, only static files (css, js etc). Still, the same relative name results in a name clash.

Comment: Where do the names end up clashing?   What is it that can't tell which base.html (for example) should be used for each application, given that each application's base.html is in its own template folder?

Comment: @knbk: thanks for refreshing my memory, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @GreenAsJade: if two Django apps both have `base.html` and they're both located in the `/templates/base.html` of that app, how would Django know which template to use? It'll iterate over all the apps to find the template and use the first one, it doesn't have specific logic that says which one to prefer.

Comment: I had imagined that it would know that it is being referenced from an app1 view, therefore it is app1/templates/base.html that needs to be used!    I think that you and knbk are both clarifying for me that the template finder doesn't know which app it is trying to find the template for.   That's a bit suprising!     It makes me think it would make more sense to have all templates in project/templates/appname, since this appears to be the way that the finder sees it!   What's the advantage of having a directory called project/appname/templates? (I hope you can grant me this followup question!)

Comment: @GreenAsJade: when each Django app has a templates directory, you can easily put the Django app in another project (or share it online) and things will still work. So Django will know how to find templates by looking in the templates directory of each app. Having all templates in one templates directory would be a hassle when you need to put together the contents of that directory yourself.

Comment: Got it!   I don't yet have enough experience to even visualise the need for sharing one app from a project without the others :) Good to know what's down the road and how to prepare for it.